# Problems getting Wygwam's has_excerpt feature working with Low Variables

Tags: wygwam, low-variables

I'm using Low Variables (2.3.3) with a Wygwam (2.7) variable type.

Is it possible to get the has_excerpt functionality working in this setup?

I've tried the following code but it ignores it and just outputs the tag:

```
{lv_my_variable:has_excerpt}
```

Wondering if I'm doing something wrong, or whether it's just not supported? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The variable syntax, `{lv_my_variable}`, doesn't support any additions or variations like that. It's like a Snippet or Global Variable: just as is. For extra processing, you'd need to use the tag syntax: `{exp:low_variables:single var="lv_my_variable"}`.

However, getting to additional options like the `:has_excerpt` function is up to the fieldtype author to implement. Something like `{exp:low_variables:single var="lv_my_variable" method="has_excerpt"}` would be nice in this case. But, again, that's up to Pixel & Tonic to add support for.

Comment: Thanks for confirming, Low. I'll tweet this link to Pixel & Tonic so they know it's a feature request.